# How do you save nested objects in rails 3?

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I've been trying to find a solution to the following problem. I have three types of objects: A,B och C. C contains B and B contains A. What i wanna do is this:

A.new(:b = > B.new(:c => C.new)).save

but that failes, and I'm forced to do it the other way around. Any ideas on how I can write it? The current code looks like this:

```
  B.transaction do |t|
    b = B.create(:object => @object)
    C.create(:b => b)
  end
```

Comment: The object is not being created. The child object is missing.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

You should put in model A:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :b_model
```

in model B:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :c_model
```

Then type:

```
params = { :a_model => {
               :name => 'i belong to a', 
               :b_attributes => {
                                 :title => 'I belong to b' 
                                 :c_attributes => {
                                                   :city => "I belong to c"
                                                  }
               }
            }
          }

a = AModel.create(params[:a_model])
```

See examples [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help. I'm using similar code as the one above in other parts of the application - and it works great. However, in this particular case it's not a form issue. I want to be able to create an object, with a child object and save both at once.  Can't active record figure out the dependencies, i.e. save the has_many first and then write the belongs_to to the database?

Comment: mmmm, the problem here lies with te `id` that need to be exist for the associations. Does B contain `a_id` and C contain `b_id``?

Comment: `C.new` has an id of `nil` until it's created in the database. ActiveRecord would have to save `C` then `B` then `A`, which apparently it isn't doing in this case.

Comment: Yup! Thanks. I kind of feel that you should be able to instantiate a new object, add some other new objects to it... and save it all. I basically wanna do the reverse of what works :). Activerecord should be smart enough to figure out the dependencies and save them in the right order. Does it seem reasonable to add a patch for this?